# how to use the crypto object (key) after passing the fingerprint authentication activity and handler to encrypt something in android?

Tags: android, authentication, encryption, fingerprint

i have the source code below to generate key and initialize the Chiper for the encryption later after passing the fingerprint authentication (with some global variable)

```
private KeyStore keyStore;
// Variable used for storing the key in the Android Keystore container
private static final String KEY_NAME = "androidHive";
private Cipher cipher;
private TextView textView;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
protected void generateKey() {
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
    try {
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        keyGenerator.init(new
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(
                        KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
            | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public boolean cipherInit() {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/" + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/" + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,
                null);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return true;
    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    }
}
```

and the function is called like this after the fingerprint authentication code in fingerprint activity

```
generateKey();

if (cipherInit()) {
    FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
    FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
    helper.startAuth(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);
}
```

and this is the FingerprintHandler code

```
private Context context;

// Constructor
public FingerprintHandler(Context mContext) {
    context = mContext;
}

public void startAuth(FingerprintManager manager, FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {
    CancellationSignal cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    manager.authenticate(cryptoObject, cancellationSignal, 0, this, null);
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationError(int errMsgId, CharSequence errString) {
    this.update("Fingerprint Authentication error\n" + errString);
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpMsgId, CharSequence helpString) {
    this.update("Fingerprint Authentication help\n" + helpString);
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
    this.update("Fingerprint Authentication failed.");
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
    ((Activity) context).finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

private void update(String e){
    TextView textView = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.errorText);
    textView.setText(e);
}
```

after the authentication success in directing the activity to HomeActivity and i want to encrypt something with key that already generated and Chiper that already initialized earlier in the HomeActivity but i dont know how to call the key and Chiper that already generated before, any example how to do the encryption after the fingerprint authentication ? its for my final project on college, so i'm really appreciated anyone who can answer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you generated the key in the keystore it's pretty easy. You just need to use the same initialization vector (IV) to encrypt and decrypt.

```
// encryption
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] ivBytes = cipher.getIV();
String dataToEncrypt = "Super secret data";
byte[] data = dataToEncrypt.getBytes();
byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);

// decryption
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivBytes);
byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
String originalData = new String(decryptedData);
```

**EDIT :**

I'm not sure you can pass the Cipher through activities, but you can retrieve the key in the KeyStore from any activity for sure. You just need the keyname you used to generate the key :

```
SecretKey cipherKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey("keyName", null);
```

Then you need to initialize the Cipher again.

**Important :** Every time you want to encrypt a data you need to initialize the Cipher, otherwise it will throw an exception telling that you can't use two times the same initialization vector (IV) for encryption.

Comment: may be my question isn't so clear, i mean the key generated on the other activity, in this case "FingerprintActivity" and the cipher to encrypt is initialize in the same activity (FingerprintActivity), and my question is that possible for me to use the same cipher object that already initialize in the FingerprintActivity or the key that already generated and stored in KeyStore on another activity like HomeActivity ? if yes i want to know how to take the key from the KeyStore from anothher activity (not FingerprintActivity) so i can use the same key to encrypt another data on another activity

Comment: by the way thnk you very much for your response, really appreciate it :)

Comment: I edited my post, hope it answers to your question ;) By the way, I'm currently working on a library for fingerprint authentications. You might want to take a look : [https://github.com/omaflak/FingerprintDialog-Library](https://github.com/omaflak/FingerprintDialog-Library)

Comment: wow that edited answers really help, hahaha thnk you so much, thats the answer that i really need, i have stuck about 1 week without any progress cause of this problem, hahaha... and the sad thing is my final project have rule that i cant use any library, need to "manual coding" itself, and i hate that, i dont even know if i use the encryption with "android style" with generating key, and initiating cipher is allowed, cause its could be called "built-in function" almost like using library, really hate this strict unreasonable rule -_- by the way i'll absolutely try your library later, thnks ;)

Comment: Haha you're welcome ! Good luck with your project, I hope you won't get any trouble :p

Comment: yeah, thnks haha... by the way do you know whats the difference in "Key" and "SecretKey" ?

Comment: Key is not a class,
it's an interface  [https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Key.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Key.html)